# Problem with Update Extension Caller ID | Ring Central

Tags: ringcentral, caller-id

I am using CURL in the developer portal and keep getting an error that the phoneNumber is invalid. What a I doing wrong?

curl --request PUT \
  --url 'https://platform.devtest.ringcentral.com/restapi/v1.0/account/~/extension/~/caller-id' \
  --header 'accept: application/json' \
  --header 'authorization: Bearer [[CODE]]' \
  --header 'content-type: application/json' \
  --data '{"byDevice":[{"device":{"id":"88","uri":"https://platform.ringcentral.com/restapi/v1.0/account/88/device/88","phoneNumber":"Ext. 101 Other Phone"},"callerId":{"type":"PhoneNumber","phoneInfo":{"id":"2025731036","uri":"https://platform.ringcentral.com/restapi/v1.0/account/88/phone-number/2025731036","phoneNumber":"+19703002096"}}}]}'

Answer (score 0):

As per this link below you question is answered:
https://forums.developers.ringcentral.com/questions/8899/problem-with-update-extension-caller-id.html

The API reference given is incorrect.
It is here suggest to remove the "uri" and "phoneNumber" key/value pair from the "device" object as well as the "uri" and "phoneNumber" from the "phoneInfo" object can be omit as per the above link